# how to reset variable after selecting?

Tags: angularjs

Hello I'm building a project with angular and php. I have a "select" option wich I can choose and it shows me all the "categories" I need and I need to select one. then it can calaculate the quantity of "products" when I pick a "category". but when I pick another "category" the total is no reset to 0 to count again it just counts more. can someone please help?

this is my code:

Html:

```
     <select ng-model="stockReport.selectedOption" 
ng-change="computeTotal()" ng-options = "item.category_name for item in stockReport |
            unique:'category_name'">

            <option value="">בחר קטגוריה</option>
            </select>



 <div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="customer-list table table-striped" >
            <thead>
                 <tr >
                     <th class="Column-Header">קטגוריה</th>
                    <th class="Column-Header">קוד מוצר</th>
                     <th class="Column-Header">שם מוצר</th>
                     <th class="Column-Header">תיאור מוצר</th>
                     <th class="Column-Header">כמות במלאי</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 <tr ng-repeat="item in stockReport" ng-if = "item.category_name == stockReport.selectedOption.category_name"
                  ng-init="setTotals(item)">
                     <td>{{item.category_name}}</td>
                     <td>{{item.stock_id}}</td>
                     <td>{{item.product_name}}</td>
                     <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                     <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                 </tr>
             </tbody>
             <tfoot>

                 <tr class="bg-warning">
                     <td><font size="6">סך הכל מוצרים במלאי:</font></td>
                     <td><font size="6">{{total}}</font></td>
                     <td></td>
                 </tr>
             </tfoot>
         </table>


 </div>
```

Controller function that calculate:

```
  $scope.total = 0;
      $scope.setTotals = function(item){
              // $scope.total = 0;
            if (item){


                 $scope.total += parseInt(item.quantity);
                 console.log($scope.total);
                 return $scope.total;


            }

        }
```

Comment: **the total is no reset to 0 to count again it just counts more. can someone please help?** Can't get the meaning of this

Comment: @SyamPillai yes:) the total doesn't reset to - 0 each time I pick a category. it continues to count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want the sum of all the `quantity` of the table entry. Then you need to change the HTML code also

**HTML**:

```
<tbody>
             <tr ng-repeat="item in stockReport" ng-if = "item.category_name == stockReport.selectedOption.category_name"
              ng-init="setTotals(stockReport)">
                 <td>{{item.category_name}}</td>
                 <td>{{item.stock_id}}</td>
                 <td>{{item.product_name}}</td>
                 <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                 <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
```

**OR**

```
<select ng-options="......" ng-change="setTotals(stockReport)"></select> //this is better option and remove ng-init
```

**JS**:

```
$scope.setTotals = function(totalItem){
    $scope.total = 0;
     for(var item in totalItem){
       if (totalItem[item] && (totalItem[item].category_name == $scope.stockReport.selectedOption.category_name)){
         $scope.total += parseInt(totalItem[item].quantity);
         console.log($scope.total);
         return $scope.total;
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: than it calculates only one row(the last one) each time i pick a category. but yes it resets to -0

Comment: So for each time you need to call the function twice?? ie., the final total will get after two iteration of the function?? Am I correct?

Comment: when I enter the page - total = 0:, I pick a category for example ("football") and I get 4 rows with team names and quantity of money each team has. then the total function will calculate how much money they all have. and when I choose another category "basketball", it will count the their money plus the total in the "football" category

Comment: So you don't want to add money of `football` with money of  `basketball`.
if i'm selecting `football`, it should show money of `football` only. like that for `basketball` also

Comment: This solution is bad: it uses ng-init, although it's clearly documented as "shouldn't be used". It computes the total for every item in the collection, although it doesn't need to be computed as many times. And it won't recomputed the total if there is no item in the collection after the category is changed. Use ng-change, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Also, `for (var in ...)` is not how you should iterate on an array.

Comment: But `for (var in ...)` should perfectly work. I'm sure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Comment: @tanyaa Can you please provide your code in a jsFiddle??

Comment: how ?I don't use jsFiddle

Comment: can we use the chat here?

Comment: Give more code of your javascript atleast. Basically the `$scope.stockReport`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121086/discussion-between-tanyaa-and-syam-pillai).

Answer (score 0):

`ng-init` should almost never be used. It's clearly said in the documentation.

If you want the total to be computed every time the selection changes, use ng-change:

```
<select ng-model="stockReport.selectedOption" ng-change="computeTotal()" ...>
```

Or, if the total computation is fast enough, just compute it every time you need it:

```
<td><font size="6">{{ computeTotal() }}</font></td>
```

The computeTotal function should look like this:

```
$scope.computeTotal = function() {
    var total = 0;
    $scope.stockReport.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item.category_name == stockReport.selectedOption.category_name) {
            total += parseInt(item.quantity)
        }
    });

    $scope.total = total;
    // or, if you choose the second option of computing it every time you need it:
    // return total;
}
```

Note that you shouldn't use `<font>`. Use CSS.

Comment: Then edit your question, and post the code you tried (HTML and JS)

Comment: You haven't really read my answer. You're still using ng-init, although I started my answer by saying it should never be used. And you haven't even created a computeTotal() function: how could computeTotal() in the view do anything if the function doesn't even exist? I edited my answer to add the computeTotal() function, but really, you need to think about what you're doing.

Comment: you didn't said to create a computeTotal() function. I have I function that I'm using for that. about the ng-init --> I forgot to delete it when I edtied here. I deleted in my code . thanks anyway for trying to help . I'm new with this and I'm sorry I didn't understand you completely.

Comment: That's extremely basic stuff. You can't expect a call a computeTotal() function in the view to work fine if that function doesn't even exist. I thought this was pretty obvious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121084/discussion-between-tanyaa-and-jb-nizet).